# How to add an image into word file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-word, ms-office, xml-namespaces

This is part of the code to create a word file from a javascript function

I want to add an image in the file (the image must be physical on the server hard disk not a URL on the internet)

how to achieve this

```
                   var templateHeader = '<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"\
                                xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"\
                                xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"\
                                xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"\
                                xmlns:css="http://macVmlSchemaUri" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">\
                                <head>\
                                <meta name=Title content="">\
                                <meta name=Keywords content="">\
                                <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=unicode">\
                                <meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>\
                                <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 14">\
                                <meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 14">\
                                <link rel=File-List href="Customer%20(5)_files/filelist.xml">\
                                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\
                                 <w:WordDocument>\
                                  <w:View>Print</w:View>\
                                 </w:WordDocument>\
                                </xml><![endif]-->\
                                <style>';
        
            templateHeader += '<!--@page WORDSECTION1 {mso-page-orientation:potrait;} -->';

        templateHeader += '</style></head><body bgcolor=white lang=EN-US style=\'tab-interval:36.0pt\'><div class=WordSection1>';
        var templateFooter = '<p class=MsoNormal style=\'mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto\'><span style=\'mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman"\'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p></div></body></html>';

        var charset = document.characterSet || document.charset;

        saveAs(new Blob(["\ufeff", templateHeader + "This is my file" + templateFooter], {
            type: 'application/msword;charset='+ charset,
            encoding: charset
        }), "filename" + '.doc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the rest is also HTML, the image can be added as HTML as well:

```
var image = '<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/fda292124649edada394b86c22a9103d?s=64&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" width="32" height="32">';
function getDataUri(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        // Get raw image data
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

        // ... or get as Data URI
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    };

    image.src = url;
}

// Usage
getDataUri(image, function(dataUri) {
   saveAs(new Blob(["\ufeff", templateHeader + "This is my file" + dataUri + templateFooter], {
        type: 'application/msword;charset='+ charset,
        encoding: charset
    }), "filename" + '.doc');
});
```

Comment: this will only load the image if connected to the server via internet or locally if the web application is on an intranet .. is there a way to load even if not connected to a server ?